getting a 419 err code while calling POST method to pterodactyl panel api
What is pterodactyl panel?
Pterodactyl® is a free, open-source game server management panel built with PHP, React, and Go. Designed with security in mind, Pterodactyl runs all game servers in isolated Docker containers while exposing a beautiful and intuitive UI to end users.
You can check out the pterodactyl panel in there github.
And this is their api documentation
Issue
I was using the pterodactyl panel api by POST method to create a new user in the panel. I tried it using Postman API platform for testing if it works and it actually worked all good. But when I implemented it in my ReactJS app using fetch function, it returned a very weird response with a 419 error. I am not sure if this type of error is common or not, also I faced this error first time so I have no idea. Would be very grateful if any help is received. :)
Code
    const currUser = auth.currentUser
    const pass = generatePassword()
    const userData = {
        email: currUser.email,
        first_name: currUser.displayName,
        last_name:'',
        username: currUser.email,
        password: pass
    };
    let reqOpts = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': api_key,
        },
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(userData)
    }
    let uri = api_uri+"/api/application/users"
    await fetch(uri, reqOpts)
    .then(res=>{
        if(!res.ok) {
            throw new Error('Pterodactyl Panel API resonse is NOT OK \nStatus : ' + res.status)
        }
        return res.json()
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
        alert(err)
    })

Error and the response received
screenshot here
I tried to create an user with my app's authorized user's details in the pterodactyl panel. I expected a good 200 status response with the details of the created user in the panel.

mode: 'no-cors',  this will literally never work for you. Why did you add it?

Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors

oh... i was getting the cors err and when i looked up it told me if i dont care about the response data then i can use that...... so what do i do to get rid of the cors err if i the mode: 'no-cors' won't work?

"if i dont care about the response data"... your code seems to indicate you do. There are also restrictions on the type of request data you can send with no-cors. See this answer

Access to fetch at 'https://cant.show.address/api/application/users' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
this error is saying is the api server is sending blank Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header value, right? i need to fix that server right?
